# Socket hang up for chrome-aws-lambda with Lambda Runtime 10.x

Tags: aws-lambda, puppeteer, chrome-aws-lambda

I have below code

```
 browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--single-process', '--start-maximized', '--headless', '--window-size=1920,1080', '--disable-gpu','--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
        executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
        headless: true,
        devtools: false,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    });
```

I am getting below error saying Socket hangup. How can I fix it to run puppeteer on lambda

```
enter c2021-02-23T18:10:22.895Z 09b30961-2493-4d86-83aa-f7d243f46a7c    INFO    Error in PDF generation ErrorEvent {  target: WebSocket {    _events: [Object: null prototype] { open: [Function], error: [Function] },    _eventsCount: 2,    _maxListeners: undefined,    _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',    _closeCode: 1006,    _closeFrameReceived: false,    _closeFrameSent: false,    _closeMessage: '',    _closeTimer: null,    _extensions: {},    _protocol: '',    _readyState: 3,    _receiver: null,    _sender: null,    _socket: null,    _bufferedAmount: 0,    _isServer: false,    _redirects: 0,    _url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:37077/devtools/browser/3a65ff8c-2cae-4e89-bc43-5c4c7a2e7abf',    _req: null,    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false  },  type: 'error',  message: 'socket hang up',  error: Error: socket hang up      at connResetException (internal/errors.js:609:14)      at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:458:23)      at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)      at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {    code: 'ECONNRESET'  }}ode here
```

Comment: how did you fix this error ?